# SD Card RAID System

Tags: raid, sd-card

Is it possible to setup a RAID system with SD-cards? Of course, the system would work better if all of the cards are exactly the same. If it is possible, can all or most operating systems handle this setup?

Comment: Yes, but this would be about as useful as raiding floppy disks. :)

Comment: Could you make that an answer and explain why so I can mark your answer as the answer?

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson If possible, specify a destination RAID on SD cards. Robotics, photoeqipment, something else ... ?

Comment: @STTR, I do not fully understand the meaning of your comment. Could you try to explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson Purpose/function SD RAID?

Comment: @STTR, I was just curious as to whether an SD-card RAID system would be possible. I was thinking about designing a mobile Raspberry Pi robot with an SD-card RAID system. I decided not to, but I was still curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make software RAID's almost over whatever the hell you want, however it's really not going to be all that useful since RAID setups almost certainly cause more write operations, especially when rebuilding, so your SD cards will wear out a lot sooner.

In addition to that, cheap SD card readers aren't really designed for data throughput, so you will have to put quite some money into those two card readers in order to use your also not too cheap high speed SD cards.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, you may be a lot better off with a small SSD instead of SD cards.

Comment: Maybe he's just trying to learn about RAID on the cheap.

Comment: Then he should grab a bunch of old hard drives.

Answer (score 14):

Well, why. There RAID on SD cards. For example, for those who collect mobile robotics.

[image]

[image]

[MS robots & mechanical men](http://www.msrobots.net/msrobots.aspx)

[The Pocket Mini Computer](http://propellerpowered.wikispaces.com/Pocket+Mini+Computer)

Well, remember that this is just P8X32A 8 cores, that does not compare like with Tilera). In general, it is more like an example.

[Get 64GB CompactFlash--via 4 microSD cards](http://news.cnet.com/8301-17938_105-10274902-1.html)

> PhotoFast's CR-7200 CompactFlash card adapter is capable of holding
>   four microSD cards and combining their storage space.

[image: CR-7200 CompactFlash card adapter]

Comment: MS Robots seems to have become msrobotics.net ... not sure though. :-/